# I have multiple error when i try to sign-up with email and another error when i try to login

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

1. when i register i must not succeed in doing it several times with the same e-mail i must return 'Email already exists'
2. when i logged i have an error 'Email does not exists' and i can not connect

here are my login and sign-up functions

```
@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST']) 
def login() :
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('password')

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, password):
                flash('Logged in successfully!', category='success')
                login_user(user, remember=True)
                return redirect(url_for('views.home'))
            else:
                flash('Incorrect password. Try again!',category='error')
        else:
            flash('Email does not exist.', category='error')


    
    return render_template("login.html", boolean=True)

@auth.route('/sign-up',methods=['GET','POST'])
def sign_up() : 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        first_name = request.form.get('firstName')
        password1 = request.form.get('password1')
        password2 = request.form.get('password2')

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user:
            flash('Email already exists.', category='error')
        elif len(email) < 4 :
            flash('Email must be greater then 3 characters.', category='error')
        elif len(first_name) < 2 :
            flash('First name must be greater then 1 characters.', category='error')
        elif password1 != password2 :
            flash('Password don\'t match.', category='error')
        elif len(password1) < 7 :
            flash('Password must be greater then 6 characters.', category='error')
        else :
            new_user = User(email=email, first_name=first_name,password=generate_password_hash(password1, method='sha256'))
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit
            login_user(user, remember=True)
            flash('Account created!', category='success')
            return redirect(url_for('views.home'))

    return render_template("sign_up.html")
```

I want to sign up with one email and also one for each user and to resolve the login error please.```

Comment: You are not calling `db.session.commit`, you need to call it like `db.session.commit()`

Comment: think's azro , now when i sign up i have anther error 'AttributeError' AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_active'

Comment: Your code does not contain `is_active` part. But most likely you are not checking for non existent user (None) somewhere

Comment: in your db class try to set a defult value for is_active for etc default=False and in your singup method try to handel your password - email name and ... in your flask forom

Comment: in flask login there is a class call current_user its have methods like is_authenticated its return true if your current user is login for sure not loggin user is is_anonymous and dont have a is_active attribute